# Installing Nortons or Trend on Windows Vista Non SP1

Tags: windows-vista, anti-virus

I have a customer with a Windows Vista Machine without SP1. Have tried installing SP1 but it blue screens. I have also, contrary to the specifications on Nortons 360 and Trend Micro Maximum Security, tried to install them without luck. I do not need both Nortons 360 and Trend Micro, just one of them to work as an AV.

Any suggestions to get it up and running. Prefer not to reformat as this is a main business computer.

Comment: Use older versions of these products that do support Vista RTM.

Comment: disable all 3rd party tools (Clean boot: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135) and try to install the Sp1 and Sp2